# How to unload self.view from UIViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

According to [View Controller Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH10-SW15), we can explicitly unload `self.view` from `UIViewController` by assigning `nil` to `self.view`.

But in Swift, `view` property in `UIViewController` is declared as

```
var view: UIView
```

It's not `UIView!` and thus following code not compiles

```
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    if self.view.window == nil {
        self.view = nil
        //          ^ Type 'UIView' does not conform to protocol 'NilLiteralConvertible'

    }
}
```

Is there another way to do it in Swift?

Comment: self.view.removeFromSuperview()

Comment: @ArturKucaj: …is something completely different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`setValue(nil, forKey:"view")` seems to work:

```
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    if self.view.window == nil {
        self.setValue(nil, forKey: "view")
    }
}
```

Comment: That the `view` property doesn't allow setting nil is probably a bug in the audited Swift API. (Per advice on Apple's developer forums, you should [file a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com) about that with #IUO in the title.) This is a good workaround, though.

Answer (score 3):

You are no longer expected to unload the view. This is why `-[UIViewController viewDidUnload]` is deprecated. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidUnload) says:

> Deprecated in iOS 6.0. Views are no longer purged under low-memory conditions and so this method is never called.

In the *View Controller Programming Guide*, it says:

> The memory used by a view to draw itself onscreen is potentially quite large. However, the system automatically releases these expensive resources when the view is not attached to a window. The remaining memory used by most views is small enough that it is not worth it for the system to automatically purge and recreate the view hierarchy.

In other words: if the view hierarchy is attached to a window, it *can* consume a lot of memory. But if the view hierarchy is not attached to a window it's pretty cheap.

So the answer is: don't try to unload your view. It wouldn't give you much memory back anyway. Of course, if you can release any objects that you can restore/recalculate (like caches), do so in `didReceiveMemoryWarning`.

Comment: I understand why views are no longer released automatically. But, I want to centralize the initialization process for all resources at `viewDidLoad`. So when I release something, I want to also release the `view`.

Comment: Even though views are automatically released, and the view hierarchy itself doesn't maintain costly resources, there's still value to nil'ing out a view controller's main view: many VCs centralize state setup in `viewDidLoad`. That may include heavyweight non-view-hierarchy state data, and any custom views in the view hierarchy might also reference non-view data. Nuking it all from orbit is a way to be sure that a) it's all gone and b) it all gets reinitialized on the same code path as normal initialization once it's needed again.